# What is the maximum value of $x^T Ax$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

Let $$A = \begin{bmatrix}3 &1 \\  1&2\end{bmatrix}$$ What is the maximum value of $x^T Ax$ where the maximum is taken over all $x$ that are the unit eigenvectors of $A$?

1. $5$
2. $\frac{(5 + \sqrt{5})}{2}$
3. $3$
4. $\frac{(5 - \sqrt{5})}{2}$

---

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $\frac{5 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$. What is $x^T Ax$? Can you explain a little bit, please?

Comment: $x=(x_1,x_2)^T$ then $x^TAx=(x_1,x_2)A(x_1,x_2)^T$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $x\neq 0$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with unit length and associated eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $x^TAx=x^T\lambda x=\lambda x^Tx = \lambda$. So the maximum value of $x^T Ax$ where the maximum is taken over all $x$ that are the unit eigenvectors of $A$ is simply the value of the largest eigenvalue of $A$.

As pointed out by @Ant, the quantity $x^TAx$ arise in the Rayleigh quotient associated to $A$ (note that $A$ is symmetric). In fact, one can show that the eigenvectors (resp. eigenvalues) of a symmetric matrix $M$ are the critical points (resp. values) of the function 
$$R(x)=\frac{x^TMx}{x^Tx}$$
which is called the Rayleigh quotient associated to $M$.

Answer (score 7):

This is an immediate application of this result from Raleigh.. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient

Comment: Thanks for nice article/answer.

Answer (score 6):

OK, Let us say that the eigenvalue of $A$ is $\lambda$ and then call the corresponding eigenvector $x_{\lambda}$ and hence

$$Ax_{\lambda}=\lambda x_{\lambda}$$

and observe that

$$x_\lambda ^TA{x_\lambda } = \lambda x_\lambda ^T{x_\lambda } = \lambda (1) = \lambda $$

so you should find the maximum eigenvalue of $A$. So the maximum value of the quadratic form will be $\frac{5 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for beautiful explanation.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay: You are welcome! :)

Answer (score 2):

$$x^TAx=\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}= 3x_1^2 + 2x_1x_2 + 2x_2^2$$

Comment: I need to find maximum value, from this function, rt?

Comment: Using the (unit) eigenvectors, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Here $A=\begin{bmatrix} 3 &1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}_{2\times 2}$

For finding the eigenvalue:

Characteristic equation:$|A-\lambda I|=0$ where $I$ is called identity matrix.

$\Rightarrow|A-\lambda I|=\begin{vmatrix} 3 &1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{vmatrix}-\lambda\begin{vmatrix}  1&0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix}=0$

$\Rightarrow \begin{vmatrix} 3 &1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{vmatrix}-\begin{vmatrix}  \lambda&0 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{vmatrix}=0$

$\Rightarrow \begin{vmatrix} 3-\lambda &1 \\ 1 & 2-\lambda \end{vmatrix}=0$

$\Rightarrow(3-\lambda)(2-\lambda)-1=0$

$\Rightarrow 6-3\lambda-2\lambda+\lambda^{2}-1=0$

$\Rightarrow \lambda^{2}-5\lambda+5=0$

Now$,\lambda =\frac{-(-5)\pm \sqrt{25-20}}{2}$

$\lambda =\frac{5\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$

So$,\lambda_{1} =\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\lambda_{2} =\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Let Eigenvector $X=\begin{bmatrix} x_{1}\\x_{2} \end{bmatrix}_{2\times 1}$

Now find the Eigenvectors:

$AX=\lambda X$

$\Rightarrow AX-\lambda X=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\Rightarrow(A-\lambda I )X=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 3-\lambda &1 \\ 1 & 2-\lambda \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_{1}\\x_{2} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$------------$>(1)$

Put $\lambda=\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 3-(\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2}) &1 \\ 1 & 2-(\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2}) \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_{1}\\x_{2} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}\frac{6-5-\sqrt{5}}{2} &1 \\ 1 &\frac{4-5-\sqrt{5}}{2} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_{1}\\x_{2} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} &1 \\ 1 &\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_{1}\\x_{2} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

Perform some row operation

$R_{1}\rightarrow\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}R_{1}$

$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}).(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})&\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \\ 1 &\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_{1}\\x_{2} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1-5}{4}&\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \\ 1 &\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_{1}\\x_{2} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}-1&\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \\ 1 &\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_{1}\\x_{2} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

Again do some operation $R_{2}\rightarrow R_{2}+R_{1}$

$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}-1&\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \\ 0 &0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_{1}\\x_{2} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

Here $Rank (A)=1$ and $number$  $of$  $unknowns$ $ =2$

clearly see $r(A)<UK(1<2),$So $UK-r(A)=2-1=1$ value assign to the one unknowns.[This is case of infinite solutions]

So, $x_{2}=k$ and $-x_{1}+(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})x_{2}=0$

$ -x_{1}=-(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})k$

$ x_{1}=(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})k$

Therefore $X=\begin{bmatrix} x_{1}\\x_{2} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})k \\k \end{bmatrix}$

$X=\begin{bmatrix} x_{1}\\x_{2} \end{bmatrix}=k \begin{bmatrix}(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}) \\1 \end{bmatrix}$

Now, find the unit vectors of $A:$

$\hat{u}=\frac{\vec{X}}{|\vec{X}|}$

$|\vec{X}|=\sqrt{(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{2}+1^{2}}=1.9$

$\hat{u}=\frac{\begin{bmatrix}(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}) \\1 \end{bmatrix}}{1.9}$

$\hat{u}=\begin{bmatrix} 0.85\\ 0.52 \end{bmatrix}$

here in given question  $\hat{u}=x=\begin{bmatrix} 0.85 \\0.52 \end{bmatrix}$ and $x^{T}=\begin{bmatrix} 0.85 &0.52 \end{bmatrix}$

Now $x^{T}Ax=\begin{bmatrix} 0.85 &0.52 \end{bmatrix}_{1\times 2}\times \begin{bmatrix} 3 &1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}_{2\times 2}\times \begin{bmatrix} 0.85 \\0.52 \end{bmatrix}_{2\times 1}$

$x^{T}Ax=\begin{bmatrix} 3.6 \end{bmatrix}_{1\times 1}$

and similarly do for $\lambda=\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}$

$X=\begin{bmatrix} x_{1}\\x_{2} \end{bmatrix}=k \begin{bmatrix}(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}) \\1 \end{bmatrix}$

Now, find the unit vectors of $A:$

$\hat{u}=\frac{\vec{X}}{|\vec{X}|}$

$|\vec{X}|=\sqrt{(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{2}+1^{2}}=1.2$

$\hat{u}=\frac{\begin{bmatrix}(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}) \\1 \end{bmatrix}}{1.2}$

$\hat{u}=\begin{bmatrix} -0.52\\ 0.83 \end{bmatrix}$

here in given question  $\hat{u}=x=\begin{bmatrix} -0.52\\0.83 \end{bmatrix}$ and $x^{T}=\begin{bmatrix} -0.52 &0.83 \end{bmatrix}$

Now $x^{T}Ax=\begin{bmatrix} -0.52 &0.83 \end{bmatrix}_{1\times 2}\times \begin{bmatrix} 3 &1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}_{2\times 2}\times \begin{bmatrix} -0.52 \\0.83 \end{bmatrix}_{2\times 1}$

$x^{T}Ax=\begin{bmatrix} 1.33 \end{bmatrix}_{1\times 1}$

So, we get a maximum value $x^{T}Ax=\begin{bmatrix} 3.6 \end{bmatrix}_{1\times 1}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2} \end{bmatrix}$

and minimum value $x^{T}Ax=\begin{bmatrix} 1.33 \end{bmatrix}_{1\times 1}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2} \end{bmatrix}$